# ASP.NET Check if localization resource exists

Tags: resources, localization, asp.net-4.0, exists

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 and have resource files (like labels.en-EN.resx) and manage them using the ResourceManager object.

How can I check if there is no translation file for a specific culture? (Besides checking if the compiled localization dll exists in the BIN folder)

Comment: Sorry if this seem a stupid question, but why do you need to check this in the first place? Another question that comes to my mind, is why you implement this thing manually? Do you have some strange requirement(s) that force you to use non-standard mechanism?

Comment: I include the culture in the URL (/en-EN/test.aspx), I want to check if the first part is a correct culture, or do a redirect 500 to the default if not.